# Strange behaviour using pass-by-reference / dereferencing

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, dereference

Here is my demonstration code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WORK 0

typedef struct FooStruct {
    int x;
} FooStruct;

void setX(FooStruct *foo_ptr) {
    FooStruct foo = *foo_ptr;

    if (WORK) {
        foo_ptr->x = 10;
    } else {
        foo.x = 10;
    }
}

FooStruct makeFoo() {
    FooStruct foo = { 0 };

    setX(&foo);

    return foo;
}

int main(void) {
    FooStruct foo = makeFoo();

    printf("X = %d\n", foo.x);

    return 0;
}
```

If WORK is defined to be 1, the code executes as expected and prints "X = 10".

However, if WORK is set to 0, it instead prints "X = 0", or if the FooStruct isn't default initialised (i.e. change FooStruct foo = {}; to FooStruct foo;), valgrind will throw a value uninitialized error on the printf line.

I'm sure this is due to a gap in my understanding, but to me the two different WORK branches should essentially be identical in operation, so I'm not sure where the misunderstanding is coming from.

This is compiled with gcc 8.2.0 with/without valgrind with equal results.

=======================

EDIT:

Simplified example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WORK 0

void setX(int *x_ptr) {
    if (WORK) {
        *x_ptr = 5;
    } else {
        int x = *x_ptr;
        x = 5;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int x = 0;
    setX(&x);

    printf("X = %d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think both versions should be identical? That's exactly the difference between "pass by value" and "pass by reference/pointer"

Comment: You can dumb this down to `void set_x (int* ptr)
{
  if(foo)
  {
    *ptr = 5;
  }
}`. Is it so strange that whatever ptr points at isn't affected and remains 0 when foo is zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code seems to be working as expected when you `#define WORK 0` too.  If you set a member in a copy of a structure, you shouldn't expect the original to be modified.

You have:

```
void setX(FooStruct *foo_ptr) {
    FooStruct foo = *foo_ptr;

    if (WORK) {
        foo_ptr->x = 10;    // Modify the structure pointed to by foo_ptr
    } else {
        foo.x = 10;         // Modify the local copy of the structure
    }
}
```

Because you've made an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — thanks!), there is nothing done with the modified copy of the structure in `setX()`.

Comment: Ah I see! So when you dereference a pointer within a function, it doesn't actually dereference to the same section of memory on the heap that the pointer is pointing to, it allocates new memory on the stack and copies the value there instead? 

I think majority of my confusion comes from that I've learnt that `ptr->x` is an alias to `(*ptr).x`, so `Foo f = *ptr; f.x` would be equivalent from what I can tell, but it obviously isn't based on the example and what you've said.

Comment: Yes; the `foo` in the `setX` function is a local variable that you initialize by copying the contents of `*foo_ptr` into the local variable.  Using `ptr->x` is 'the same as' `(*ptr).x` except it is shorter and more readable, especially in nested contexts: `ptr1->struct2->member3` is easier to read (and heaps easier to type!) than `(*(*ptr1).struct2).member3`, so use arrows `p->x` with pointers and do not use starry dots (`(*p).x`). In your `Foo f = *ptr;` example, you're initializing rather than assigning.  There are differences. After initialization, `f.x` refers to the local `f`, not `*ptr`.

Comment: I've updated the op with a more simplified example that demonstrates the same concept, and removed my references to structs because it clearly had nothing to do with that.

Thanks for the explanations, it's really helped! My only question is: is there a way to have a `Foo*` (say, passed by reference in the current function) and convert that into a `Foo` type where it *does* point to the same section of memory as the original `Foo*`? Or is that just not possible in C? Thanks again.

Comment: You'd have to have `FooStruct *foop = foo_ptr;` and then use `foop->x = 10;` in the function, which has the same effect as using `foo_ptr->x = 10;` in the function.  If you want to refer to the same memory, use the pointer notation.  If you make copies (`FooStruct foo = *foo_ptr;`), then by definition the memory in the local variable is distinct from the memory at the far end of the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

In this function:

> ```
> void setX(FooStruct *foo_ptr) {
>     FooStruct foo = *foo_ptr;
>
>     if (WORK) {
>         foo_ptr->x = 10;
>     } else {
>         foo.x = 10;
>     }
> }
> ```

, `foo` is a *local variable* of type `FooStruct`.  Therefore, no modification the function performs on `foo` produces any effect visible outside the function.

That `foo` is initialized with a copy of the contents of the `FooStruct` to which parameter `foo_ptr` points is irrelevant.  In particular, it does not make the function's local `foo` be an alias for whatever `foo_ptr` points to.

On the other hand, if the function modifies the object to which `foo_ptr` points, then of course that is visible to any other code that can see that object, directly or indirectly.